# Calling matlab from Unix command line

Tags: unix, matlab

I have a Matlab script named "main_wrapper.m" in my /home/user/MATLAB directory. I want to call this script from the Unix command line. This script ends with a quit, so it's expected to quit by itself. I want to call this script from the command line and have it quit all by itself.

I don't get results with:

`shell$ cd /home/user/MATLAB/ && /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/matlab -nosplash   -nodesktop -r main_wrapper.m`

or with

`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/matlab -r " cd /home/user/MATLAB; run (/home/user/MATLAB/main_wrapper); end; quit "`

In either case MATLAB window opens up and doesn't run by itself.

> How can I get the window to quit?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [answer by @Simon on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337137/983722):

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "my_script; quit"
```

#### Edit:

Following Edric's recommendation, you'd better use one of these:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, my_script; end, quit"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, my_script; catch, disp('failed'), end, quit"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, my_script; catch e, your_error_handling_function(e), end, quit"
```